# Record button works only once in android audio recording application

Tags: android

I have developed an android app that records users voice. Its a learning app for me. However the problem is that the record button works only once and the second time when I hit record it does not stop at all. There are total four buttons Record-Stop record. Play-stop play.

The exact problem is that when second time record is pressed the stop button stays greyed out.

The third time I press record the application crashes directly.

```
package com.example.soundrecorder;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.PermissionInfo;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.UUID;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnRecord, btnStopRecord, btnPlay, btnStop;

    String pathsave="";
    MediaRecorder mediaRecorder;
    MediaPlayer mediaplayer;

    final int REQUEST_PERMISSION_CODE=1000;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Request Runtime Permission
        if(!CheckPermissionFromDevice())
            requestPermissions();

        //init view
        btnPlay = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
        btnRecord = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStartRecord);
        btnStop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStop);
        btnStopRecord = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStopRecord);


            btnRecord.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                                             @Override
                                             public void onClick(View view) {

                                                 if(CheckPermissionFromDevice())

                                                 {

                                                 pathsave = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/"
                                                         + UUID.randomUUID().toString()+"_audio_record.3gp";
                                                 setupMediaRecorder();
                                                 try{
                                                     mediaRecorder.prepare();
                                                     mediaRecorder.start();

                                                 }catch (IOException e){
                                                     e.printStackTrace();
                                                     }
                                                     btnPlay.setEnabled(false);
                                                    btnStop.setEnabled(false);
                                                 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Recording...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                                 }
                                                 else
                                                 {
                                                     requestPermissions();
                                                 }
                                             }
                                         });
            btnStopRecord.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    mediaRecorder.stop();
                    btnStopRecord.setEnabled(false);
                    btnPlay.setEnabled(true);
                    btnRecord.setEnabled(true);
                    btnStop.setEnabled(false);

                }
            });


        btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
            btnStop.setEnabled(true);
            btnStopRecord.setEnabled(false);
            btnRecord.setEnabled(false);

            mediaplayer = new MediaPlayer();
            try{
                mediaplayer.setDataSource(pathsave);
                mediaplayer.prepare();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            mediaplayer.start();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Playing...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        btnStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                btnStopRecord.setEnabled(false);
                btnRecord.setEnabled(true);
                btnStop.setEnabled(false);
                btnPlay.setEnabled(true);

                if(mediaplayer !=null)
                {
                    mediaplayer.stop();
                    mediaplayer.release();
                    setupMediaRecorder();
                }

            }
        });


    }

    private void setupMediaRecorder() {
        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(pathsave);


    }

    private void requestPermissions()
{
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,

    },REQUEST_PERMISSION_CODE );
}


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode)
        {
            case REQUEST_PERMISSION_CODE:
            {
                if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Permission Granted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Permission Denied",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
                break;
        }
    }

    private boolean CheckPermissionFromDevice()
    {
        int write_external_storage_result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        int record_audio_result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO);
        return write_external_storage_result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && record_audio_result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a `btnStopRecord.setEnabled(true);` in the `btnRecord` click function. If you can stop the first recording, it's probably because the stop record button is enabled by default, but when you press it, it disables itself. You should probably initialize the enabled state of your buttons too, but this should solve your problem:

```
public void onClick(View view) {

    if(CheckPermissionFromDevice())
        pathsave = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/"+UUID.randomUUID().toString()+"_audio_record.3gp";
        setupMediaRecorder();
        try{
            mediaRecorder.prepare();
            mediaRecorder.start();
            btnStopRecord.setEnabled(true); //enable stop record
            btnPlay.setEnabled(false); //shouldn't be able to play while recording too
            btnRecord.setEnabled(false); //yours to see if should be able to restart record while recording, but probably not if it crashes
            btnStop.setEnabled(false); //probably should be disabled too on record

//...rest of the function
```

Comment: This did solve it thanks.
Although I want to ask a question.
I have recorded a song on default android recorder and my own recorder.
The android default recorder has better quality than my own recorder any idea why?

Comment: You're welcome! No idea, sorry, if you don't find any answer here on SO, you should aks a separate question..